# Trigger on PostGIS line layer occurs twice

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

Using [this](http://twiav-tt.blogspot.com/2013/04/postgis-trigger-function-keeping-track.html) tutorial, I've established a SQL trigger in order to track changes on a PostGIS layer. It works great for a point layer. However, using the script below, it causes problems with line layer, as all of the triggers occur twice.

I first realized this because the history table inserts lines for the 'INSERT' and 'UPDATE' logic twice (not for 'DELETE', surprisingly). The notices print to the console twice for 'INSERT' 'UPDATE' and 'DELETE'.

For example:

- When creating a line in the base table, the history table creates two objects with the same attributes except for the hid (history table id).
- When updating the attribute of an existing line, in the history table, three objects are created:
  1) One with etat = 'MODIFICATION COURANTE' (resembles the existing feature in the base table, including the updated attribute)
  2) Two with etat = 'MODIFICATION ARCHIVEE' -- one with the old attribute value and one with the new attribute value. At this point, I am expecting only one object containing the old attribute. The object containing the new attribute is out if place.

  ```
  --CREATE TRIGGER
  CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test.test_track_history_tracker() RETURNS trigger AS
  $new_test_track_history_tracker$
              BEGIN
              -- INSERT
              IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                             INSERT INTO test."Conduite_test_history"
                                             (diametre, type, materiau, origininfo, dtreno, dtpose, reparateur, dt_dmd, id_sig, gid_org, created, created_by, modified, etat, geom)
                             VALUES
                                             (NEW.diametre, NEW.type, NEW.materiau, NEW.origininfo, NEW.dtreno, NEW.dtpose, NEW.reparateur, NEW.dt_dmd, NEW.id_sig, NEW.gid, current_timestamp,
                                             current_user, FALSE, 'CREATION', NEW.geom);
                             raise notice 'Insert happened';
                             RETURN NEW;

              -- UPDATE
              ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                             UPDATE test."Conduite_test_history"
                                             SET deleted = current_timestamp, deleted_by = current_user, modified = TRUE, etat = 'MODIFICATION ARCHIVEE'
                                             WHERE deleted IS NULL and gid_org = OLD.gid;
                             INSERT INTO test."Conduite_test_history"
                                             (diametre, type, materiau, origininfo, dtreno, dtpose, reparateur, dt_dmd, id_sig, gid_org, created, created_by, modified, etat, geom)
                             VALUES
                                             (NEW.diametre, NEW.type, NEW.materiau, NEW.origininfo, NEW.dtreno, NEW.dtpose, NEW.reparateur, NEW.dt_dmd, NEW.id_sig, NEW.gid, current_timestamp,
                                             current_user, FALSE, 'MODIFICATION COURANTE', NEW.geom);
                             raise notice 'Update happened';
                             RETURN NEW;

              -- DELETE
              ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
                             UPDATE test."Conduite_test_history"
                                             SET deleted = current_timestamp, deleted_by = current_user, etat = 'SUPPRESSION'
                                             WHERE deleted is NULL and gid_org = OLD.gid;
                             raise notice 'Delete happened';
                             RETURN NULL;
              END IF;
  END;

  $new_test_track_history_tracker$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  --ADD TRIGGER
  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_test_track_history_tracker ON test."Conduite_test";
  CREATE TRIGGER trg_test_track_history_tracker AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON
  test."Conduite_test"
              FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.test_track_history_tracker();
  ```

Comment: Although you have a spatial database trigger functions aren't often used in GIS systems, I think you would get a better reception posting this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ as the instance of the trigger is SQL and is not concerned with geometry or geography objects.

Comment: The trigger looks OK. It is likely being set twice on the main table (with different name), or once on the main table and another time on the history table itself. It would explain the update behavior: 1st call: set current value to "archivee", insert new row with "courante" values. 2nd call: change the "courante" value (inserted a moment ago) to "archivee" and insert a new "courante" value. --> 1 old "archivee", 1 new "archivee" and 1 new "courante"